# Probability of returning to the origin for a 3 dimensional random walk

Tags: python, probability, random-walk

Here is my code simulating a code in python simulating a random walk in 3 dimensions. It returns a percentage of times the walk returns to the origin. Polya's constant was ~ 34% probability for a walk to return to the origin in 3 dimensions. My percentage is only 11-12%. If I multiply by three (as a guess) the answer becomes fairly close to Polya's constant but it looks closer to 36% most of the time. Please let me know what the error in my math, logic or coding for this problem is. Thanks in advance.

```
def r3walk(T):
x = np.zeros((T))
y = np.zeros((T))
z = np.zeros((T))
count = 0
for t in range(1,T):
    walk = random.uniform(0.0,1.0)
    if 0 < walk < 1/float(6):
        x[t] = x[t-1] + 1
    elif 1/float(6) < walk < 2/float(6):
        x[t] = x[t-1] - 1
    elif 2/float(6) < walk < 3/float(6):
        y[t] = y[t-1] + 1
    elif 3/float(6) < walk < 4/float(6):
        y[t] = y[t-1] - 1
    elif 4/float(6) < walk < 5/float(6):
        z[t] = z[t-1] + 1
    else: 
        z[t] = z[t-1] - 1
for t in range(1,T):
    if [x[t],y[t],z[t]] == [0,0,0]:
        count += 1
return count/float(T)
```

Edited Code:

```
def r32walk(T):
x = np.zeros((T))
y = np.zeros((T))
z = np.zeros((T))
count = 0
for t in range(1,T):
    walk1 = random.uniform(0.0,1.0)
    if walk1 > 0.5:
        x[t] = x[t-1] + 1
    else:
        x[t] = x[t-1] - 1
for t in range(1,T):
    walk2 = random.uniform(0.0,1.0)
    if walk2 > 0.5:
        y[t] = y[t-1] + 1
    else:
        y[t] = y[t-1] - 1
for t in range(1,T):
    walk3 = random.uniform(0.0,1.0)
    if walk3 > 0.5:
        z[t] = z[t-1] + 1
    else:
        z[t] = z[t-1] - 1
for t in range(1,T):
    if [x[t],y[t],z[t]] == [0,0,0]:
        count += 1
#return x,y,z
return count/float(T) * 100
```

Comment: I think your approach is completely wrong; you are simulating a single walk and measuring how often it returns to the origin, not simulating multiple walks and measuring how many return to the origin within some number of steps.

Comment: I checked this by doing it the way I would interpret it, and got 0.341, 0.351 and 0.334 for three sets of 1000 simulations of up to 1000 steps.

Comment: I tried to implement your approach but I obviously came up against more errors because I got basically zero percent. Can you clue me in further to how you approached the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I approached this as a [Monte Carlo](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) simulation problem; make a large number of random walks, and see what proportion return to the origin within some large number of steps. The easiest implementation is one function to do a single walk, and a second to do the repetition.

```
import random

def simulation(dimensions, repeats, steps):
    """Simulate probability of returning to the origin."""
    return sum(random_walk(dimensions, steps) 
               for _ in range(repeats)) / float(repeats)

def random_walk(n, s):
    """Whether an n-D random walk returns to the origin within s steps."""
    coords = [0 for _ in range(n)]
    for _ in range(s):
        coords[random.randrange(n)] += random.choice((1, -1))
        if not any(coords):
            return True
    return False

print [simulation(3, 100, 1000) for _ in range(10)]
```

The larger `steps` and `repeats` become (i.e. the closer we get to the "real" situation, all possible walks with an infinite number of steps), the less variability in the output I'd expect. For the numbers shown, I get:

```
[0.33, 0.36, 0.34, 0.35, 0.34, 0.29, 0.34, 0.28, 0.31, 0.36]
```